# python tkinter - Bind a "Global" key shortcut which can be triggered from outside the window

Tags: python, tkinter, binding, ttk

I am thinking if there is any way to bind "GLOBAL" key bindings to tk/ttk widgets

for example:
in this code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def output(lines = 'hehehehe'):
    print(lines)

root = tk.Tk()

button = tk.Button(root, text ='HAHAHA', command = lambda:output('hahaha'))
button.pack()

root.bind('<Control-a>', output)
root.mainloop()
```

now, whenever i hit Control+A when the window is active, the function `output()` works..

But, when i start any other window and make this tk-window inactive, The key bindings doesn't work...

Is there any way to bind "GLOBALLY"?

Comment: using `keyboard` module (`pip install keyboard`), don't think there is a built-in `tkinter` method for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible, you cannot access global key-strokes within `tkinter`, you will have to use some other external library like `keyboard`, should be fairly easy.

First install the library with `pip install keyboard`, then:

```
import tkinter as tk
import keyboard

....
keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+a', output, args=('From global keystroke',))
root.mainloop()
```