# How to bind callback functions globally to a widget type in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, binding

I have summarized the script in such a way that it only shows what is necessary to show my **problem**. In short, I would like to `globally` bind the callback functions to all `button` type widgets in the **app**.

```
class Frame_1(Frame):
    def__init__(self,master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.btn_0 = Button(self, text='Press 10')
        self.btn_0 .pack() #...

        # links that I would like to disappear 
        # and replace with a global link that only reaches button type widgets
        self.btn_0 .bind('<ButtonPress>', self.master.press)
        self.btn_0 .bind('<ButtonRelease>', self.master.release)


class Frame_2(Frame):
    def__init__(self,master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.btn_0 = Button(self, text='Press 10')
        self.btn_0 .pack() #....
        self.btn_0 .bind('<ButtonPress>', self.master.press)
        self.btn_0 .bind('<ButtonRelease>', self.master.release)


class Controller(Frame):
    def__init__(self,master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.frm1 = Frame_1(self, bg='blue')
        self.frm1 .pack()
        self.frm2 = Frame_2(self, bg='green')
        self.frm2 .pack()

    def press(self, e):
        print('press')
    def release(self, e):
        print('release')
        

root=Tk()
app=Controller(root)
app.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Globally? You will have to use 3rd party libraries. Does this answer your question? [python tkinter - Bind a "Global" key shortcut which can be triggered from outside the window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68924619/python-tkinter-bind-a-global-key-shortcut-which-can-be-triggered-from-outsid)

Comment: Thanks for answering, what I intend is not to repeat the code ```bind ('<ButtonPress>', callback) ``` and ```bind ('<ButtonRelease>', callback)``` because it seems primitive to do it , since if there is some way not to repeat it I would like to know, I have been thinking about ```bind_class``` and ```bind_all```, but I don't know how to apply it

Comment: `bind_class` applies to specific widget class, like if you apply it for a button, the binding will apply for all the buttons

Comment: @CoolCloud But how should I implement it? If you could help me a little, I would appreciate it.

Comment: `self.bind_class('Button', '<ButtonPress>',self.master.press)` and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tkinter provides a `bind_class` method that allows you to bind to a widget class rather than an individual widget. In your case, the class would be `Button`.

Your code might look something like this:

```
root=Tk()
app=Controller(root)

root.bind_class("Button", "<ButtonPress-1>", app.press)
root.bind_class("Button", "<ButtonRelease-1>", app.release)
```

Answer (score 0):

try it this way:
you tried to call "self". At this point you need an object reference. But you didn't have that. Public objects can still be integrated into a class.

```
from tkinter import *


def press( event):
    print('press')

def release( event):
    print('release')


class Frame_1(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)

        self.btn_0 = Button(self, text='Press 10')
        self.btn_0.pack()  # ...

        # links that I would like to disappear
        # and replace with a global link that only reaches button type widgets
        self.btn_0.bind('<ButtonPress>', press)
        self.btn_0.bind('<ButtonRelease>', release)


class Frame_2(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.btn_0 = Button(self, text='Press 10')
        self.btn_0.pack()  # ....
        self.btn_0.bind('<ButtonPress>',  press)
        self.btn_0.bind('<ButtonRelease>', release)


class Controller(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        global press, release
        self.frm1 = Frame_1(self, bg='blue')
        self.frm1.pack()
        self.frm2 = Frame_2(self, bg='green')
        self.frm2.pack()



root = Tk()
app = Controller(root)
app.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Although your suggestion helps me to wonder if the structure I am using is not adequate, it does not solve my question of not repeating the code for each button because there are many buttons and there must be some way not to repeat the links in each one. I appreciate the suggestion.